# Shrinking pg_toast on RDS instance

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-rds, vacuum, autovacuum

I have a Postgres 9.6 RDS instance and it is growing 1GB a day. We have made some optimizations to the relation related to the pg_toast but the pg_toast size is not changing.

Autovacuum is on, but since autovacuum/VACUUM FREEZE do not reclaim space and VACUUM FULL does an exclusive lock, I am not sure anymore what the best approach is.

The data in the table is core to our user experience and although following [this](https://lob.com/blog/running-vacuum-full-on-rds-postgres-with-minimal-downtime) approach makes sense, it would take away the data our users expect to see during the vacuum full process.

What are the other options here to shrink the pg_toast?

Here is some data about table sizes. You can see in the first two images, that the relation `scoring_responsescore` is relation associated with the pg_toast.

[image]
[image]

**Autovacuum settings**

[image]

Results from current running autovacuum process for that specific pg_toast. It might help.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`VACUUM (FULL)` is the only method PostgreSQL provides to reduce the size of a table.

Is the bloated TOAST table such a problem for you? TOAST tables are always accessed via the TOAST index, so the bloat shouldn't be a performance problem.

I know of two projects that provide table reorganization with only a short `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock, namely [pg_squeeze](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_squeeze) and [pg_repack](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack/), but you probably won't be able to use those in an Amazon RDS database.

To keep the problem from getting worse, you should first try to raise `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit` to 2000 for the affected table, and if that doesn't do the trick, lower `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay` to 0. You can use `ALTER TABLE` to change the settings for a single table.

Comment: pg_repack works on RDS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.pg_repack

Answer (score 0):

pg_repack still does not allow to reduce the size of TOAST Segments in RDS.
And in RDS we cannot run pg_repack with superuser privileges, we have to use "--no-superuser-check" option. With this it will not be able to access the pg_toast.* tables.